# Changes to config/mongoid.yml does not automatically load in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Every time I make a change to the file I have to load the config manually in console:

```
Mongoid.load!("path/to/your/mongoid.yml")
```

I tried putting this line in `application.rb` did not work.
Also made an initializer for it, again did not work.

How may I have mongoid config loaded automatically on rails console startup?

Note: Server automatically picks that up on startup. but console does not

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution myself.
made a file `~/.irbrc` and put the following line in it:

```
Mongoid.load!("#{Rails.root}/config/mongoid.yml")
```